# Sending money from my account with node.js and Paypal REST API

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-rest-sdk

I need to send money from company's Paypal account to another Paypal account.
Is it possible to do with Paypal's REST API (if so, how)?
Or must I use the adaptive payments API (that doesn't have an official Paypal SDK)?

Answer (score 0):

Send money from your account has not been added to their REST APIs yet.  You can see the operations that they have available [here](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#api-operations).  To automate the send money, you can choose from either their Adaptive Payments Implicit Send Money (here are links to the [SDK](http://paypal.github.io/sdk/), [Integration Guide](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-accounts/integration-guide/ACIntroduction/) and the [API references](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/#ap)) or the MassPay APIs (again, links to the [Merchant SDK](http://paypal.github.io/sdk/), [Integration Guide](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/mass-pay/integration-guide/MassPayOverview/) and the [API reference](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/#merchant)).

You would need to create an APP to run the Adaptive Payments send money [here](https://www.paypal-apps.com/user/my-account/applications) or contact PayPal's customer support to get Mass Payments turned on in your account